# Bootstrap 4 - How to make elements change location based on page width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

On my contact page below the form, I have a Google Maps iframe, then a vertical line, and then a bunch of contact information all on the same line.

The vertical line is achieved by setting a right border on the column containing the Google Map, then setting padding on the right side of the left column and the left side of the right column.

Unfortunately, when I resize the page, the contact information drops down without the vertical line. What I would like to do is to make the vertical line disappear, the contact information drop down to the next line, and to create a horizontal line between the Google Map and the contact info.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:4em">
  <h3 class="h1 text-center" style="padding-bottom:1em">Our Classroom</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="padding-right:1em; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d198741.27545049458!2d-77.15466081348372!3d38.893512762965!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89b7c6de5af6e45b%3A0xc2524522d4885d2a!2sWashington%2C+DC!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1560167966705!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="padding-left:20px">
      <p>address</p>
      <p>phone</p>
      <a href="mailto:email">email</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really have no clue how to do this, being very new to Bootstrap, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you written the styles into the div elements for the purpose of asking your question_ or are they coded in this way?

Comment: They are coded in this way. Yes, bad convention, but I plan to clean everything up later.

Comment: if they are coded like this then the responsive design of Bootstrap won't work for you and any effects would be 'unpredictable' _ Your styles need to be coded pretty much from the outset and separated with media queries so that the format of the page (or the elements around the form you're designing) respond to the size of the screen that is viewing your page _ 
This is the fundamental purpose of Bootstrap _ If you want BS4 to work for you (at least as a beginner) then you should consider using the framework in a conventional way and pretty much according to BS4 guidelines _

Comment: to clarify with just one example from your code: if the padding-top style is coded into the div .container element_ then regardless of the size of the viewing screen_ the padded space will always be 4em (and therefore 'unresponsive' to the viewing device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with help of media query

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .iframe_block {
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
} 

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .iframe_block {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding-top:4em;">
    <h3 class="h1 text-center" style="padding-bottom: 1em;">Our Classroom</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm iframe_block" style="padding-right:1em;">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d198741.27545049458!2d-77.15466081348372!3d38.893512762965!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89b7c6de5af6e45b%3A0xc2524522d4885d2a!2sWashington%2C+DC!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1560167966705!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm" style="padding-left:20px">
            <p>address</p>
            <p>phone</p>
            <a href="mailto:email">email</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! With a little modification for some other CSS I had, it worked!

Comment: glad you like my answer